# Permissions error trying to delete default content from a Document Set

Tags: document-set

I have created a custom document set type on a SharePoint site of which I am the owner (but I am not the administrator at my company).

When you create a new Proposal (the name of the custom document set), two documents are automatically added: a proposal template (pptx) and a prioritization template (xlsx).

Recently, I updated the prioritization template, and I started by uploading the new copy (which has a slightly different name).

[image]

However, when I try to delete the old version (by clicking "Delete" and then "OK"), I get an error:
[image]

As the owner, I can request access and then approve that same request, but I still receive the same error when attempting to delete the file.

I've also tried making another person an owner on another PC and having them try, but they get the same error. I've tried in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.

I can, however, upload NEW documents:

[image]

I'm at a loss for what to try next. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I was going through Site Settings, choosing the content type, and then modifying the default content from there.

The resolution was to go through the Library Settings, choose the content type, and modify the default content from there.